# NSDictionary fast KVC with nil values

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

Not sure if I named the question correctly but here goes:

Lets say I have a JSON response being returned from an API. The JSON gets parsed using `SBJson` which works flawlessly. An example of JSON:

```
{
    "value": 15199,          //this field is required
    "value_str": "$1.5k",    //this field is required
    "change": 33             //this field is optional
}
```

Now this gets parsed in a neat little `NSDictionary` from which I can read. So far I had it like so:

```
//lets assume that "dict" is the parsed JSON using SBJSON
NSDictionary *number = @{@"value_str": [dict objectForKey:@"value_str"]}; //this works
number = @{@"value_str": [dict objectForKey:@"value_str"], @"change": [dict objectForKey:@"change"]}; //this crashes if there was no "change" in JSON
```

So the crash occurs because I'm trying to set a `nil` value as an object to a `NSDictionary` which isn't allowed. This would work if the `change` field was always there though. How to fix this?
Do I really have to do it like:

```
NSDictionary *number = [NSDictionary dictionary];
[number setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"value_str"] forKey:@"value_str"];
[number setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"change"] forKey:@"change"];
```

and so on for every key-value pair in the dict? This is much more slower and painful to write.  There has to be a better way, right? Please? :)

Oh and if I set the `setValue ForKey` and then query like `objectForKey` will I get the object (or value) which I set with `setValue ForKey`?

**EDIT:** I got an idea but I am not sure how to implement it efficiently. Instead of checking for every key here and so on why not subclass `NSDictionary` and override the `@{}` constructor which is `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys` I think. I am familiar with compiler `va_list`s but I do not have enough knowledge to implement such a constructor efficiently. If someone would do this it would be awesome.
The whole idea is to check values in that constructor method and if the object is `nil` just skip it. How's that? Can someone make it tick or is it a bad idea?
**EDIT2:** Found out that subclassing is a bad idea :) used solution provided in the comments.

Comment: Why not write a foreach loop to iterate and set value for all keys that exists in json ?

Comment: Because lets say I don't always need the "value" and if the dictionary would have 100 entries that would be pretty inefficient.

Comment: I think u need to check every time that there is a key "change" exists. If yes then extract that key-value, and in else do not extract it. I can only see this way right now.

Comment: What's the point in transcribing the objects from one dictionary to another? Why not copy the dictionary, or use the same dictionary object?

Comment: +1 to this question. The best workaround I've seen is `@{@"key": keyValue ? : [NSNull null]}`. This will add the `keyValue`, if not `nil` or `null` if `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About first question I think the best deal is to check value every time, or to make a copy of dictionary.

About second question:

`objectForKey:` accepts any object as a key, not just strings. The only requirement is that the key support the `NSCopying` protocol.

Another difference is that if you give a nil value to `setValue:forKey:`, it removes the key from the dictionary if it exists, otherwise does nothing. But if you give a nil value to `setObject:forKey:`, it raises an exception.

When you do `valueForKey:` you need to give it an `NSString`, whereas `objectForKey:` can take any `NSObject` subclass as a key. This is because for Key-Value Coding, the keys are always strings.

In fact, the documentation states that even when you give `valueForKey:` an `NSString`, it will invoke `objectForKey:` anyway unless the string starts with an @, in which case it invokes `[super valueForKey:]`, which may call `valueForUndefinedKey:` which may raise an exception.

Comment: The second part makes it clear all right but I'm after the inserting nil values into NSDictionary part. Got an idea to subclass it. Check the edited question.

Comment: Really i think it's bad idea to subclass nsdictionary. 
check subclassing notes.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html .
@guilherme give good workaround : @{@"key": keyValue ? : [NSNull null]}

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSArray *keysArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"value",@"value_str",@"change", nil];

NSDictionary *dict =[[NSDictionary alloc]init]; // your service response dict
NSMutableDictionary *savedict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; // finally saved dict

for (int i=0; i<[[dict objectForKey:@"your parentkey here"] count]; i++) {

    if ([dict objectForKey:keysArray[i]]) {
        [savedict setObject:[dict objectForKey:keysArray[i]] forKey:keysArray[i]];
    }
    else
    {
        [savedict setObject:@"" forKey:keysArray[i]];

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is a way indeed, but when I have a lot of situations like the one described above (there are more optional attributes, and a lot more formats) it becomes quite impractical. Your solution definitely works but I'm looking for something a bit neater.